# elasticsearch-py connection pool

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

Doc just shows how to create a connection with
`Elasticsearch()`

Not sure if I'm reusing connection(using connection pool) in my django view.

Do I need to setup something special to use connection pool or is it just given automatically as database connection pooling?

Comment: I've similar problem. Does it keep the connection open or does it recreate it everytime?

Answer (score 1):

The [ConnectionPool](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/connection.html#connection-layer-api) is only used if multiple connections are defined. You can use the [add_connection](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/connection.html#elasticsearch.Transport.add_connection) method of the Transport class to add multiple connections.

Comment: can we get an example for the usage of `elasticsearch.ConnectionPool` class??